# certificate verify failed after deleting .pth files in site-packages

Tags: python, ssl-certificate

So when I download a package (`site-packages`), from bitbucket, using this command-line:
`pip install --upgrade git+ssh://git@bitbucket.ggf.com:7999/pyt/jira`, pip starts to not work.

I tried to debug and find the issue in this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\importlib\_common.py", line 89, in _tempfile
    os.write(fd, reader())
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\importlib\abc.py", line 371, in read_bytes
    with self.open('rb') as strm:
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\importlib\_adapters.py", line 54, in open
    raise ValueError()
ValueError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\configuration.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import (
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\exceptions.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.models import Request, Response
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import certs
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 177, in _exec_module
    notify_module_loaded(module)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\wrapt\decorators.py", line 470, in _synchronized
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 136, in notify_module_loaded
    hook(module)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\certifi_win32\wrapt_pip.py", line 35, in apply_patches
    import certifi
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 177, in _exec_module
    notify_module_loaded(module)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\wrapt\decorators.py", line 470, in _synchronized
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\wrapt\importer.py", line 136, in notify_module_loaded
    hook(module)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\certifi_win32\wrapt_certifi.py", line 20, in apply_patches
    certifi_win32.wincerts.CERTIFI_PEM = certifi.where()
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\certifi\core.py", line 37, in where
    _CACERT_PATH = str(_CACERT_CTX.__enter__())
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\lib\importlib\_common.py", line 95, in _tempfile
    os.remove(raw_path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\a77870\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\3\\tmpjivq2gz5'
```

I found out that if I removed these two files from `site-packages` then pip worked again, so for some reason these files make it stuck, but I don't know why?

```
python-certifi-win32-init.pth
distutils-precedence.pth
```

Now the problem with doing this is that the package which is installed `jira`, is an API that needs to connect over SSL, and I guess by deleting these `.pth` files that this creates some error now?

I get this output running a simple command, and its trying to connect to Jira:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python3102\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python3102\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python3102\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1040, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python3102\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 414, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python3102\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python3102\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python3102\lib\ssl.py", line 512, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python3102\lib\ssl.py", line 1070, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Programs\Python\Python3102\lib\ssl.py", line 1341, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)
```

Any ideas on a way where I should delete these files?

Comment: I have to use 3.10+ (python), but yeah the only reason I tried to delete `python-certifi-win32-init.pth` was because my pip didn't work if it was there

Comment: @wovano with `python-certifi-win32-init.pth` inside my site-packages folder i get the first output from the post, no matter what command (python) I try to run containing pip

Comment: the wired thing is that i have this package running on multiple machines, but I have this one which has this error. maybe I've setup my git/python up with wrong cridentials/certificates. have been looking at this for 8 hours now, so might take a break now, and look at it tomorrow

Comment: This took waaay longer than I thought, but I finally found the problem. For some reason the new version of a site-package called `wrapt` caused all this to happen. I simply did a downgrade to the version (`wrapt==1.13.3`) one of my other machines was running (where all other stuff also works) and boom all error was gone. So there was no error with certificates or anything. I did post my error output message to the `wrapt` developers so they know there is something there.

Comment: @wovano had a machine where everything was running so made a pip freeze > req.txt file to check every version one by one, and then I just tried to update all the `pip list --outdated` packages, and when this was updated the problem occurred.

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution. You can post your solution as an answer and even mark it as accepted (since no other answers are provided yet). Maybe it's useful for others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

By removing `python-certifi-win32-init.pth` the functionality of the library is effectively lost with doing so.

Andrew Leech, the author of `python-certifi-win32`, [suggests to move on](https://gitlab.com/alelec/python-certifi-win32/-/issues/14#note_876668521) to his other project [pip-system-certs](https://gitlab.com/alelec/pip-system-certs) . Drop-in replacing the library with `pip-system-certs` ([PyPI link](https://pypi.org/project/pip-system-certs/)) solved all issues for me.